# How to distribute a Blazor Server-Side webapp for local use?

Tags: c#, azure-devops, packaging, blazor-server-side, software-distribution

I developed a `Blazor Server-Side` webapp for my private use. Now I want to provide this webapp to some friends, so they can use it too. I do not want to host it somewhere due to network latency, hosting costs etc.

My idea is that they run there own copy locally, just as I currently do. What possibilities do I have to distribute it? Any easy way to build an installer containing the necessary things like .NET runtime? (.NET 5.0 Preview in my case). Is it possible to automate such a build with Azure Devops, as I have my repository there?

Comment: How tech-savvy are your friends? Would they be happy to install the .NET Core SDK, clone the repo, then just use "dotnet run" for example? If so, that would be the easiest solution I suspect

Comment: Unfortunately they are not so tech-savvy. Git shouldn't be involved at all (at least not manually). Installing .NET manually could be acceptable, but with always new versions it would get annoying. So my goal would be really to provide an installer which does everything (install required .NET version, copy app somewhere).

Comment: Isn't there some sort of a "Publish" command under "Build" similar to other type of projects?

Comment: You *may* be able to publish a "single executable" version - it may well be pretty large, but that would be *much* simpler than building an installer, in my experience.

Comment: @IvanStoev thank you. I tried the publishing option in Visual Studio, looks promising,but I have issues on accessing the published webapp. More details here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63725730/sec-error-inadequate-key-usage-on-accessing-webapp-published-using-visual-studio Maybe one of you knows more about this?

Comment: @JonSkeet Tried that, ending up with issues. Can you have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63725730/sec-error-inadequate-key-usage-on-accessing-webapp-published-using-visual-studio ?

Comment: @stefan.at.wpf: No, it's not something I have familiarity with. My only advice would be "just disable https if you're only using it locally".

Comment: @JonSkeet Good idea, with that I could at least confirm that HTTPS is not the (only one) issue. For other readers, I created a more targeted questions for this new issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63732515/running-published-app-gives-cannot-find-the-fallback-endpoint-specified-by-route