# Running published app gives Cannot find the fallback endpoint specified by route values: { page: /_Host, area: }

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, blazor, publish, blazor-server-side

I created a `Blazor Server` webapp and published it from `Visual Studio` using right click on the project - publish. I am publishing to a local folder, amongst others the output includes `MyProject.exe`
Running that works fine:

```
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Now listening on: http://localhost:5000
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Now listening on: https://localhost:5001
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Hosting environment: Production
```

However I can not access my webapp on `http://localhost:5000` or `https://localhost:5001`.Chrome just gives me `HTTP ERROR 500`. In the console where I started `MyProject.exe` I can find this error:

```
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware[1]
      An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
      System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot find the fallback endpoint specified by route values: { page: /_Host, area:  }.
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.DynamicPageEndpointMatcherPolicy.ApplyAsync(HttpContext httpContext, CandidateSet candidates)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.DfaMatcher.SelectEndpointWithPoliciesAsync(HttpContext httpContext, IEndpointSelectorPolicy[] policies, CandidateSet candidateSet)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointRoutingMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitMatch|8_1(EndpointRoutingMiddleware middleware, HttpContext httpContext, Task matchTask)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.<Invoke>g__Awaited|6_0(ExceptionHandlerMiddleware middleware, HttpContext context, Task task)
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware[3]
```

Can anyone help me with this? When I run my webapp from Visual Studio, everything works fine! My `Index.razor` page is in the default `/Pages` folder.

Please note that I already checked other posts with this error:
[Cannot find the fallback endpoint specified by route values: { page: /_Host, area: }](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58874883/cannot-find-the-fallback-endpoint-specified-by-route-values-page-host-are)
It didn't change anything though.

Comment: Did you ever figure out what was causing the issue, by chance?'

Comment: @KennyMann No, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I found that a file named {project namespace}.Views.dll was not being included when publishing the project.  I was able to grab it from the bin\Release\netcoreapp3.1\ folder.  Once I copied that file to the website folder, I no longer got that error and the website worked properly.

Also, I don't know if this is a related issue, but the publish also did not include folders in the wwwroot folder.  I had to copy those over myself.